# How pass in the URL Cascading Parameters?

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2005 and I passed through the URL parameters to my report, but I only accept the first parameter and the second not because they are cascading, meaning that the parameter SecondAge depends on FirstAge.

How I deal with or can not do?

This is the URL I wrote.

http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx%2fMyFolder%2fMyReport&rs%3aparameters=false&rs%3aCommand=Render&FirstAge=2010&SecondAge=2011

Thanks

Comment: I'm also experiencing problems with this - I suspect cascading parameters are not supported via URL access, but I'm unable to find any reference that explicitly says that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a URL request like:
http://localhost/Reportserver?/MyFolder/MyReport&rc:Parameters=false&rc:LinkTarget=main&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0&FirstAge=2010&SecondAge=2011

(More documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx)

Comment: The problem is that I want to pass **cascading** parameters in the URL. I know how to pass simple parameters, but the problem arrise when the parameters are dependent of the previous ones, the values that I pass are getting cleaned up.